# How do i call async function xamarin

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to call an async function but when I try and do it it has the red line underneath it. I want the function to be called when the page is opened, thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Home : ContentPage
{


    public class GoogleProfile
    {
        public string Id { get; set;}

    }


    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await Check(/*What do i put in here*/);

    }

    public async Task Check(GoogleProfile googleprofile)
    {


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(googleprofile.Id))
        {

        }
        else {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
        }
    }




}
```

how would i call this? Sorry im new to C# and xamarin

Comment: Then put it in the event handler for when the page is open. don't do it in the constructor. If you must then you can use `Task.Run` but i advise against it.

Comment: You can't call async in constructor because when object is constructed, constructor should finish executing. Do it in an event handler or template method.

Comment: Not an actual problem but it's best to use `async Task` instead of `async void`.  Additional info [on the MSDN, by the StackOverflow regular Stephen Cleary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: @clarkitect In this example this is an Event Handler thus an exception can be made.

Comment: What if i changed it to this `static void caller(LoginPage instance, GoogleProfile googleprofile)
  {




   var ID = googleprofile.Id;

   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
   {
    instance.InitializeComponent();

   }
   else
   {
    var np = new NavigationPage(new Home());

   }` So its not async, how would i call this? sorry im new to xamarin and c#

Comment: @Nkosi Are you against Task.Run or just calling it in constructor?

Comment: @YuriS against calling it in the constructor.

Comment: `Task.Run` is equally bad especially on Xamarin Android, though it has gotten more reliable lately.

Answer (score 2):

You should make your async calls in `ContentPage.OnAppearing()`. The `OnAppearing()` event will be called, as the name suggest, right when your page is being displayed. This is the expected behavior by the user. Also note that I changed your `Check()` method to return `Task` because, if you are able to edit the method signature, always try to change the return type of async methods from `void` to `Task`:

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage {

    public LoginPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing() {
        await Check(/* Add code here to get your GoogleProfile object */);
    }

    public async Task Check(GoogleProfile googleprofile) {
        var ID = googleprofile.Id;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID)) {
            return;
        } else {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Home());
        }
    }
}
```

Technically, if you are dead set to not use `OnAppearing()` you could do the `Check()` before pushing your `LoginPage`, though without seeing more code, that would seem like it would defeat the purpose of the `LoginPage`.

Comment: Ive added this in however it still wont let me run the check method from onappearing?

Comment: @TomJefferis How is it not letting you?

Comment: In the onappearing method the check(); says it needs a parameter

Comment: @TomJefferis Oops sorry about that. Check now. Not sure how you are getting your `GoogleProfile` object though...

Comment: I have this now, `await Check(googleprofile:null);` im not to sure what to put as the arguments, also it doesn't like that the onappearing() is a void

Comment: @TomJefferis Where did you get `GoogleProfile` from...? Also what does not like `OnAppearing()`? Is there an error message? Need more info

Comment: I get it from another  page using `using Google.models;`

Comment: @TomJefferis Not sure what that is but you could pass it into the constructor of your `LoginPage`: `public LoginPage(GoogleProfile googleProfile) { InitializeComponent(); }`

Comment: I have edited the top so you can see where i get the GoogleProfile from I cant have arguments in the constructor as it wont compile

Comment: @TomJefferis That still does not really show much about the `GoogleProfile` also you can have arguments in the constructor. It works just fine for me. You must be doing something wrong. It sounds like you are having a lot of struggles with C# in general. You might want to take a step back and try and learn some of the fundamentals of C# first in order to be able to follow things a little better. Maybe find some tutorials or videos online. Or you could also check out Xamarin's Getting Started guide on their site.